# If passing a file writable stream to the Console constructor in Node.js, is writing to it asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, logging

I've read the docs about the Console object and [A note on process I/O](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o), but can't figure out if the following would result in a synchronous or asynchronous operation:

```
const out = fs.createWriteStream('./out.log')
const logger = new Console(out)

logger.log('foo')
```

I'm curious about how this acts, especially on a *Nix system.  But I wouldn't expect this to act differently on a Windows.  The reason I am asking is because I had built a logger which leveraged the Console object, but I don't want the logger to be blocking when writing logs to files while in production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be **asynchronous**.

Internally `Console` class maintains a callback [`_stdoutErrorHandler`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L55) to trigger after the write operation is completed and check for errors. We can test for asynchronicity using it.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Console } = require('console');
const str = new Array(100).fill('').map(() => 'o'.repeat(1000 * 1000)).join('');
const out = fs.createWriteStream('./o.txt');
const logger = new Console(out);
logger._stdoutErrorHandler = () => { console.log('written');};
logger.log(str);
console.log('hey');
```

You'll see that 'hey' get printed before 'written'.

[The note on process I/O](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o) applies to `process.stdin` and `process.stdout` which are special streams. When they point to files, as in the following:

```
$ node someCode.js > file.txt
```

... in Unix the write operation in Unix will be synchronous. This is handled in lines [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L88). In such cases, `process.stdout` stream will be connected to a file and not the usual unix file descriptor `fd1`.

Answer (score 5):

**tldr;**
According to Node's official documentation, what you are doing here is **synchronous** because you are using *files*.

---

> Writes may be synchronous depending on the what the stream is
>   connected to and whether the system is Windows or Unix:
>
> - **Files**:
>     synchronous on Windows and Linux
> - **TTYs (Terminals)**: asynchronous on
>     Windows, synchronous on Unix
> - **Pipes (and sockets)**: synchronous on
>     Windows, asynchronous on Unix

**Warning**: I strongly recommending not to use these synchronous actions on production services, because *synchronous writes* block the event loop until the write has completed. This can be a serious drawback when doing production logging.

Reference: [Node.js Official Documentations / A note on process I/O](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o)

Comment: This is not true. The word `stream` in the docs refers to `process.stdin` and `process.stdout` - not the stream `Console` class uses to construct the custom logger. The whole point for `Console` class was to use custom streams (files/sockets etc) which are async unlike the globally available `console` which is sync when connected to TTY and redirected to files.